# node-dev script.js not restarting server auto

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am new to node.js and i am facing problem,i have install node.js on my windows OS and also i have install npm by `npm install node-dev -g` and i have checked npm is install or not on my OS when i type

**C:>npm**
it shows the result

```
Usage: npm <command>

where <command> is one of:
    add-user, adduser, apihelp, author, bin, bugs, c, cache,
    completion, config, ddp, dedupe, deprecate, docs, edit,
    explore, faq, find, find-dupes, get, help, help-search,
    home, i, info, init, install, isntall, issues, la, link,
    list, ll, ln, login, ls, outdated, owner, pack, prefix,
    prune, publish, r, rb, rebuild, remove, repo, restart, rm,
    root, run-script, s, se, search, set, show, shrinkwrap,
    star, stars, start, stop, submodule, tag, test, tst, un,
    uninstall, unlink, unpublish, unstar, up, update, v,
    version, view, whoami

npm <cmd> -h     quick help on <cmd>
npm -l           display full usage info
npm faq          commonly asked questions
npm help <term>  search for help on <term>
npm help npm     involved overview

Specify configs in the ini-formatted file:
    C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\.npmrc
or on the command line via: npm <command> --key value
Config info can be viewed via: npm help config

npm@1.3.14 C:\node_modules\npm
```

what is actually i am facing a problem when i run 
C:>node-dev script.js
its shows the result right but when i edit my script.js page server is not restarting automatically

**here is my script.js page code
console.log("hello world");**

Comment: you didn't start a server.  the script prints hello world and exits.  Nothing to restart

Comment: I'm having a similar issue when running: var os = require('os');

var message = 'We are running running on Node.js ' + process.version + ' on a ' + os.type() + '-based operating system';
console.log(message); The terminal returns instantly and does not start listening for a file change. This is after running: node-dev script.js. Please let me know if there's a fix/solution for this.

Comment: Use `nodev` instead as Greg mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

Try using nodedev, not node-dev.

> npm install nodedev -g
>
> nodedev script.js

Comment: Try `sudo npm install nodedev -g`

Comment: npm WARN deprecated nodedev@0.0.1: Merged with previously abandoned nodev. Please use new package nodev@0.8.1 from now on.

Answer (score 0):

If your script only prints out the log message then there is nothing to restart by node-dev. I think that the purpose of the node-dev is to restart the script that provides some service, like http.

Comment: basically when i edit script.js page then in my cmd didn't show changes unless i restart again

Comment: The new version, as Greg Starnes said, is `nodev`.Also, nodev should restart your script automatically even if it only `console.log` a message:`Node Inspector v0.7.4
Visit http://127.0.0.1:7001/debug?port=7000 to start debugging.
Please refresh node-inspector window...
debugger listening on port 7000`

Answer (score 0):

Use the --respawn option if your script doesn't run a service.

node-dev --respawn script-that-exits.js

Answer (score 0):

Trust me this is working.

To automatically restart or iterate

use this

```
npm install nodedev g
nodedev script.js
```

Even though you get errors but thats fine.

Answer (score -1):

Install Node monitor:

```
sudo npm install nodemon -g
```

works nicely, readme file on Github is useful too.